# Name some sunni scholars who includes aql (intellect) as their basic principles (usul al fiqh)

Tags: fiqh

As the title says, could you name some sunni scholars (not mutazilites) that also includes intellect (aql) in their usul al fiqh to derive rules or understandings of Sharia?

Comment: I have no clue, but if they would use it they wouldn't call it aql. Note that one uses his intellect to solve any issue ;). BTW you can't address a user who wasn't active on the post's sitw.

Comment: @Medi1saif I see your point. Oh, I'll remember that to the next time.